# Problems with Tkinter Entry and .get()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having problems with my Tkinter Entry widget.
I'm just testing things out and would like to have my callback print out whatever I typed out in Entry self.a. but I'm getting this error.

> File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:/Users/Andy/testimage.py", line 146, in get
>       print a.get(self) NameError: global name 'a' is not defined

I was wondering if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. I linked the callback function correctly because if I make it print "aasdfasd" instead, it will print that when I press the button.

```
def clicked_wbbalance(self):
    self.top = Toplevel()
    self.top.title("LASKJDF...")
    Label(self.top, text="Enter low level").grid(row=0, column=0,padx=10)
    Label(self.top, text="Enter high level").grid(row=1, column=0,padx=10)
    Label(self.top, text="Values must be between 0 to 255").grid(row=3, column=0)
    Button(self.top, text="Ok", command=self.get).grid(row=3, column = 1)

    self.a =Entry(self.top).grid(row=0, column=1,padx=10)
    self.b =Entry(self.top).grid(row=1, column=1,padx=10)

def get(self):
    print self.a.get(self)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As RocketDonkey pointed out, your traceback does not match the code you posted.

Your code as written will generate a traceback like this:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The root problem is that `grid` returns `None`.  That means that attributes `a` and `b` will be `None` because they are assigned the result of calls to `grid`.  Fix that by puting object creation and widget placement on different lines:

```
self.a = Entry(self.top)
self.b = Entry(self.top)

self.a.grid(row=0, column=1,padx=10)
self.b.grid(row=1, column=1,padx=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You traceback says `print a.get(self) NameError: global name 'a' is not defined`, but the code you posted uses the syntax `print self.a.get(self)` (which would appear to be correct). Therefore if you check on line 146, you aren't prefacing `a` with `self`, meaning that instead of referencing the property `a` of the instance, you are trying to reference `a` on its own, which is not defined. Try adding `self` in front of `a` on line 146 and see if the problem continues.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Line 146 is the last line in the code I posted in my OP, which already has self in front of a

I was wondering if it might be because I'm using self.top? It's my first time using it so I'm not sure if it would affect anything.

Comment: @user1730056 Hmm, that is odd because your traceback is showing the exact line but without the `self` in front of it. Is that traceback still the same after saving the code? You should at least be seeing an error that includes `print self.a.get(self)`.